# Javascript Stopwatch Performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, stopwatch

i am trying to display multiple Running Times in a table. 
The table has 3 columns (nr, name, time). The time is displayed in that format 'hh:mm:ss.f', that means that i update the time every 100ms.

```
function updateTimes() {
    setTimeout(updateTimes, 100);
   // requestAnimationFrame(updateTimes);
    $("#livedata tbody tr").each(function (index, value) {
        var live = $(value).data("base");
        $("#" + live.Entry.Id + "_time").text(formatTimeF(moment().subtract(live.Data)));
    });
}

 //Create Table Row
function UpdateLive(live) {
    var e = $("#" + live.Entry.Id);

    if (e.length == 0) {
        e = $("<tr id='" + live.Entry.Id + "' class='live'/>");
    $("<td id='" + live.Entry.Id + "_name" + "'></td>").appendTo(e);
        $("<td id='" + live.Entry.Id + "_nr" + "'></td>").appendTo(e);
        $("<td id='" + live.Entry.Id + "_time" + "'></td>").appendTo(e);
        e.appendTo($("#livedata"));
    }
    e.data("base", live);
}
```

The code works and the time is displayed as expected on "normal" PCs, my problem are mobile Devices (Cell Phones). It seems that the update Intervall (100ms) is too fast for most of these devices, so the time starts to "jump". If I only update the times of existing table elements the "jumping" is not that hard, but if I add table rows its getting worst until the row is added.
 I use JQuery for manipulating the table.

Does anyone have an idea how i can improve my Performance?

Kind Regards
 Manu

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

1. It would certainly help to use direct references to your elements instead of accessing them by `$` selectors all the time. E.g. use `$(live.childNodes[2])` instead of `$("#" + live.Entry.Id + "_time")`, or store references to the individual cells. Then you can drop all the `id` attributes of your cells.
2. Assuming that the bottleneck is element creation, you could create hidden table rows in advance and show them once you use them, hiding them again after use. That would require a major rewrite of these functions, though.
3. I'm not sure how much overhead `$('<td>')` adds. Maybe `document.createElement('td')` is significantly faster.
4. (and this should actually come in the beginning of every performance-related change) Profile your code, e.g. using the Profile tab in Chrome's developer tools. It will show where exactly how much time is spent so that you know what the most expensive function calls are. I would assume that even if it's faster on the desktop, what's slowest on mobile will still be slowest on desktop.